# How to rotate video *.mp4 in SurfaceView?

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

Friends. Could you help me?

I need to rotate video (video must always play) on button click or other.
I show video in MediaPlayer inside SurfaceView and try this one:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
        surfaceHolder.lockCanvas().rotate(90);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stringPath);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}
```

But video don't want play. (And i don't know if it rotated)
Help me...anybody..
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well i got to rotate the video. But its not rotated in all the players. It works fine on MOV players, Quick player and android media player but on on every desptop player (MPC,VLC)

Comment: If you send the output to a TextureView (API 14+), you can specify arbitrary rotation easily.  See e.g. "Play video (TextureView)" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), particularly the commented-out call to `postRotate()`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
 surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);     
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
 int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
 int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

 surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

 if (w > h) { 
     surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(w,h);
 } else {
     surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(h,w);
 }

 surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);     
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
```

Also, maybe you would want to put that code above on your onCreate(), instead of your surfaceCreated(). And then put some play() method called from some button:

```
protected void play() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

      if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
       mediaPlayer.reset();
      }
    //Define here your filename:
    String stringPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4";

      mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);

      try {
       mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stringPath); 
       mediaPlayer.prepare();

      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

      mediaPlayer.start();
      }
```

Comment: I would expect setFixedSize() to have no effect -- the size is determined by the incoming video frames.